# Manipulaçao de streams e listas em Java

Tags: java, lista, stream-de-arquivos

Estou tentando construir um programa que lê um arquivo `csv` com informações de pacientes onde cada linha é lida do arquivo (pulando a primeira) é um armazenada em um objeto do tipo paciente com variáveis de diferentes atributos. A grande questão é que apesar de eu conseguir armazenar corretamente o conteúdo das linhas em objetos do tipo 'paciente', eu não consigo/não sei manipulá-los. Por exemplo, não consigo extrair o conteúdo da variável idade dentro do objeto paciente percorrendo a lista para obter a média de idade dos pacientes por exemplo. Não estou exibindo o objeto paciente e a função que armazena o conteúdo do arquivo csv na lista de pacientes ser grande demais e por já funcionar como o esperado.

Na função abaixo eu tento manipular a lista para obter a média de idade dos pacientes de acordo com a cidade deles. Eu não consigo extrair a idade dos pacientes, porém se eu tentar apenas imprimir a idade dos pacientes na tela de acordo com a sua cidade, eu consigo. Como faço para poder manipular e usar o conteúdo das variáveis da lista?

```
public double idadeMedia(List<Paciente> pacientes, String cidade){
    Double media;
    pacientes.stream().filter((paciente -> paciente.getMunicipio_residencia().equals(cidade)))
                .map(Paciente ->  Paciente::getIdade).average().getAsDouble();
    return media;  
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Posso ter adicionado coisas demais, mas o problema é que eu não consigo/não sei como manipular o conteúdo das variáveis dentro da lista, uma vez que eu consigo armazenar e imprimir corretamente o conteúdo do arquivo dentro dos objetos na lista, mas não consigo usar o conteúdo, como obter o valor da idade dos pacientes para calcular a media de idade, etc

Comment: Sua pergunta foi editada, é possível [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/527345/edit) a pergunta, você pode incluir novas informações ou se deseja explicar melhor algum ponto. Aqui utilizamos o editor markdown. Também foi removido mensagens de cumprimentos, [para saber mais](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/38/como-se-portar-ao-perguntar-responder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver é implementar o algoritmo que tentou utilizar no caso o `.average()` que é a média.

Uma solução simples seria re-escrever o que está tentando fazer no método `idadeMedia` uma implementação simples, sem usar o stream e etc, poderia ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
public double idadeMedia(List<Paciente> pacientes, String cidade) {
    double soma = 0;//mesmo tipo de getIdade()
    int quantidade = 0;
    for (Paciente p : pacientes) {
        if (p.getMunicipio_residencia().equals(cidade)) {
            soma += p.getIdade();
            quantidade++;
        }
    }
    if (quantidade > 0) {
        //evita divisão por zero ao calcular a média
        return soma / quantidade;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Você pode saber mais sobre o [`Arraylist`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) na documentação. Eu usei um laço for como [`iterador`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

Comment: Nossa valeu mano, muitíssimo obrigado, ajudou demais. Além de ter resolvido o meu problema, essa implementação é muito mais fácil de entender visualmente, e eu estou obtendo a média de todas cidades que eu entro o nome. Valeu mesmo

Comment: Acabou que no final das contas o problema não foi resolvido por completo, uma vez que apenas o primeiro paciente da cidade "tal" é armazenada na soma e a variavel quantidade é incrementada apenas uma vez

Comment: @YuriMachadodeVargas, poderia fornecer alguns exemplos? Eu fiz uns testes e pra mim está funcionando normal. Quando a cidade existe e quando existe mais de um paciente da mesma cidade. Pelo que entendi do seu comentário então você não quer a média de idade das pessoas da cidade, quer a média de idade de todos os pacientes da lista. É isso?

Comment: Sinto muito pela minha burrice, o seu exemplo está perfeito, é que eu acabei colocando o return dentro do for e ele encerrava logo após o primeiro detectado. Coloquei o return fora e agora funciona perfeitamente. Mais uma vez muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda, além de me ajudar com o problema me ensinou como usar esse tipo de lista.